# How to get specific value in dictionary python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have dictionary like,

```
"countries":{
    "98":{
        "uid":98,
        "title":"Switzerland"
        }
}
```

I want to get just value of "title" using ***json decoding method***.

**Note:** The value of "98" is dynamic so it changes everytime.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you have a variable `x` holding whatever `"98"` is supposed to represent, then `countries[x]["title"]` or possibly `mydict["countries"][x]["title"]` if that's actually what you have.
If not, then I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: Can you provide code in json decoding method ?

Comment: What have you tried? (also, the snippet you posted is not really valid JSON)

Comment: `[item['title'] for item in dictName['countries']]`

Comment: If you have an actual Python dictionary then you don't need json decoding. If you have a JSON file or string, then you need to make that clear in your question. Until you resolve this ambiguity your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you have several fields like `98` but they all contain a title, you could do this:

```
titles = list()
for k in my_dict["countries"].keys():

    if my_dict["countries"][k].has_key("title"):

        titles.append(my_dict["countries"][k]["title"])
```

or, as suggested in the comments

```
try:
    titles = [item['title'] for item in dictName['countries']]
except KeyError:
    print("no countries/title")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the "dictionary" you're providing is a string in JSON format and that you want to decode it into a Python object (dictionary) THEN access tittle.

If that's the case, the json module is your friend!
Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Pseudo-code

```
import json

# This is your JSON string
json_str = "......."

# This could be a dictionary, depending on the structure of the input JSON string
countries = json.loads(json_str)

# access!
target_uid = "98"

# This should print Switzerland
print(countries["countries"][target_uid]["title"])
```

Comment: According to the data `target_uid` must be a string.

Comment: @Matthias Good catch. Updated. Thanks!